# Variable memory space sharing?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In a loop, the following appends `par.fval` to `this.filters` as well as whatever `par.T` starts as:

```
<cfset par.T = this.filters />
<cfset ArrayAppend(par.T[this.name],par.fval)/>
```

Provided that all variables are defined initially and `par.fval` changes with each iteration:

```
<cfloop ...>
    <cfdump var="#this.filters#"/>
    <cfset par.T = this.filters />
    <cfset ArrayAppend(par.T[this.name],par.fval)/>
</cfloop>
```

Will dump `this.filters` for each iteration with the last value of `par.fval` appended.

I am trying to figure out why as I would have assumed ColdFusion would overwrite `par.T` as an entirely new variable.

Narrowing it down to remove logic:

```
filtersA: 
<cfdump var="#this.filters#">
<cfset par.T = #this.filters# />
<cfset ArrayAppend(par.T[this.name],par.fval)/>

filtersB: 
<cfdump var="#this.filters#">
```

Will show that `par.fval` has been appended to `this.filters` across that append statement. So for whatever reason, `par.T` appears to not become its own variable instead being a reference to the memory space of the `this`.

Comment: It's hard to understand your code example, but in CF: struct & object are passed by reference while array & simple values are passed by value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "across that append statement". Can you provide more context? What are "filtersA" and "filtersB" - components? How are they used? Are there any shared scopes involved?

Comment: Yeah, gotta say I cannot understand most of the narrative of the question. But I reckon @Henry has guessed correctly.

Comment: That code is within a cfc. At some point I use a separate function buildLinks which returns a link based on the struct par.filters. One of the options available appends extra data on one of the array filters in the struct. The problem is I need the original array to stay the same while sending in a parameter that is equivalent to the original struct with the new data appended to that that array. When I create a new local variable equivalent to the struct within the cfc and append the data to the proper array within this new struct, the data is being appended the original struct as well.

Comment: Have you tried making a deep copy of the original first ie use `duplicate()`? For next time, posting a [simple repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue will help us get to the source of the problem faster.